# Ghostscript: How to include the Apple ImageWriter drivers it used to include?

Tags: linux, macos, ghostscript

In the past, [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/index.html) used to incorporate these Apple Imagewriter devices: **iwhi**, **iwlo**, and **iwlq**. The version I had been using is gs 8.7 which is not 64-bit compliant. macOS Catalina cannot use it or any other 32 bit code, so printing to those devices fails.

More recent versions including the most recent [Ghostscript 9.27](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) omit those devices. I don't know when they were omitted or why but it seems to be a while ago. Worse, I don't know how they get incorporated in Ghostscript. Other than building gs from its source code, which I have done, I don't know where to begin. The new Ghostscript 9.27 itself works fine in macOS Catalina. It includes many "built-in" devices but the ImageWriter devices I need are absent.

The drivers and Ghostscript were originally obtained from the Linux Foundation's Open Printing website: https://openprinting.org/printer/Apple/Apple-ImageWriter_II, but they were bundled and distributed in a package form that recent macOS versions cannot handle. That web page also indicates the drivers are "Type: Ghostscript built-in" which it no longer is in recent versions.

Here is `gs -h` using the installed 32 bit version:

```
GPL Ghostscript 8.71 (2010-02-10)
Copyright (C) 2010 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
Usage: gs [switches] [file1.ps file2.ps ...]
Most frequently used switches: (you can use # in place of =)
 -dNOPAUSE           no pause after page   | -q       `quiet', fewer messages
 -g<width>x<height>  page size in pixels   | -r<res>  pixels/inch resolution
 -sDEVICE=<devname>  select device         | -dBATCH  exit after last file
 -sOutputFile=<file> select output file: - for stdout, |command for pipe,
                                         embed %d or %ld for page #
Input formats: PostScript PostScriptLevel1 PostScriptLevel2 PostScriptLevel3 PDF
Default output device: bbox
Available devices:
   alc1900 <snip> inferno iwhi iwlo iwlq jetp3852 jj100 <many other devices> <snip>
Search path:
   . : %rom%Resource/Init/ : %rom%lib/ :
   /usr/local/share/ghostscript/8.71/Resource/Init :
   /usr/local/share/ghostscript/8.71/lib :
   /usr/local/share/ghostscript/8.71/Resource/Font :
   /usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts :
   /usr/local/share/fonts/default/ghostscript :
   /usr/local/share/fonts/default/Type1 :
   /usr/local/share/fonts/default/TrueType : /usr/lib/DPS/outline/base :
   /usr/openwin/lib/X11/fonts/Type1 : /usr/openwin/lib/X11/fonts/TrueType :
   /usr/share/cups/fonts
Initialization files are compiled into the executable.
For more information, see /usr/local/share/ghostscript/8.71/doc/Use.htm.
Please report bugs to bugs.ghostscript.com.
iMac4:ghostscript-9.27 john$
```

The obvious sticking point is right there in front of me: "Initialization files are compiled into the executable." I know that, but what initialization files (if any) need to be included or modified to ensure their incorporation in the build? I have printer PPDs for the ImageWriter. They're just text files, and I *think* they would be required. Should they? How?

The only way I have attempted to build gs from source is to use `./configure` followed by `make` That begins a long compilation process that takes a few minutes, and results in an executable `gs` that works fine in Catalina. The problem is it does not include the drivers I want. Attempting to print to that printer results in it printing "Unknown device: iwhi" in straight ASCII text (not bitmapped).

By now it ought to be painfully obvious I'm well over my head and don't know where to turn. Can anyone point me in the right direction from here?

Some background can be found here: [Apple ImageWriter printer installation in… - Apple Community](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-6621)
. I wrote it. Some of its links are dead. If a picture doesn't load and you want to see it, click on it (it's a site problem).

A recent Discussion describing this dilemma is here: [32-bit ghostscript, required for ImageWriter and other printers using CUPS](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250711255)

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I shall do that!

Comment: Seems Apple is in the process of dropping support for printers not supporting IPP Everywhere. Not sure in which phase of this plan they are with Catalina. See https://ftp.pwg.org/pub/pwg/liaison/openprinting/presentations/cups-plenary-april-19.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The devices quoted were removed in this [commit](http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=commit;h=HEAD)  If you need them then you should be able to :

1. Clone our git repository, help on this is [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.27/Make.htm#Acquiring_git)
2. `git checkout a87e380acd5e326f7d4e4380348bac393fac3058`
3. copy the ghostpdl/devices/gdevadmp.c file somewhere convenient
4. `git checkout master` (or if you want a tagged release rather than the bleeding-edge code, `git checkout ghostpdl-9.27` for example)
5. copy the saved file back to ghostpdl/devices/gdevadmp.c
6. Undo the changes in contrib.mak, configure.ac and unix-gcc.mak
   (using the [link](http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=commit;h=HEAD) to the gitweb you can see the diffs, they are not
   extensive)
7. In the ghostpdl directory: `./autogen.sh` then `make`

That all assumes you have a working C compiler (gcc, make etc) and development environment, but you say you've already built GS from source so that should be fine. The end result should be a woking Ghostscript with the additional device built in.

This:

> Initialization files are compiled into the executable.

refers to the PostScript initialisation files, and won't help you with devices which are written in C and have to be compiled. While the line above is technically correct, you can use the -I switch to override the ROM file syatem (which is what that refers to) and have the initialisation files stored on disk instead.

PPD files aren't going to help you with Ghostscript, these are PostScript Printer Description files and they are used by applications which generate PostScript to customise the PostScript program for the specific printer. These are (I think) used by CUPS, but not by Ghostscript.

Answer (score 1):

I think THIS is the commit to remove gdevadmp.

I think this was removed in a flurry of activity removing stuff referred to as "moribund" MacOS and classic Mac stuff, and I think this specific removal was unwarranted and unwise, as these drivers are still in use today Using foomatic-rip:

http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=commit;h=a87e380acd5e326f7d4e4380348bac393fac3058

Comment: I was the one that made that commit and others along similar lines. The reasons being: some variants of the devices in question had bugs associated with them, or changes done to them (or requiring done), and no maintainer, and no way for us to test them. If anyone wants to volunteer to be a maintainer for a device they feel was unfairly removed, I'd be perfectly happy to reinstate the device(s) in the "contrib" directory (that is, devices not (entirely) maintained by the gs team. Although, I think everyone has to realise that, at some point, everyone has to drop support for obsolete hardware!

Comment: Chris, I'd be delighted to volunteer to maintain the ImageWriter devices. In fact I was granted the authority to edit the Open Printing page that hosts the Ghostscript and related driver packages some time ago. I realize it's been moribund and I haven't had anything to offer. Anyway, other than express my interest, I don't know what else to do. I'm not making any judgements regarding whether the removal was "unfair" or not. I'm only interested in maintaining the ability to keep those devices in service. They meet a very specific, limited purpose, and are very simple in and of themselves.

Comment: Mike, if you sign up and open a bug about this at https://bugs.ghostscript.com/ (ideally mention that you're willing to take on the maintenance), we get the ball rolling on it.

Comment: Thank you Chris, I will graciously take you up on that suggestion. Please don't conclude this late reply infers that I am not interested; it's just that I devote sporadic amounts of time to this particular project. I have the motivation, the hardware, and the desire to take on its maintenance. As long as everyone is ok with being patient I'm more than willing to accept the responsibility. I realize bug 698663 indicates its closed status, but one of the reasons given was lack of interest. Your reply of 2 years ago suggests sufficient interest is required, and I'm interested! Grant and I make 2.

Answer (score 0):

I am another Mac User and ImageWriter and ImageWriterLQ owner, I do not speak for Artifex.

at version 9.05, the file gdevadmp containing appledmp, iwhi, and iwlo, and iwlq was MOVED into the 'devices' folder. It survived there until version 9.20.

After version 9.20 it was removed in an operation that included only gdevadmp and its supporting files. The note does not say WHY it was removed.

So  a 64-bit build of ghostscript 9.20 has some potential.

The files available at:
https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/openprinting/macosx/foomatic#ghostscript_for_mac_os_x_103x_panther_-_mac_os_x_109x_mavericks

are still good, but gs and the filters need to be moved to a directory that remains accessible after the lockdown of sandboxing (about Mavericks) Suggested directory is noted in the apple support community discussion you posted earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Links on the Ghostscript web site say that THIS (StackOverflow) is the official forum for discussing issues related to Ghostscript.

If that is not appropriate, what do Artifex and Ghostscript developers suggest is the "official" forum for Ghostscript issues?

Comment: You can always open bugs on the GS bug tracker, including enhancement requests. Also it wasn't anyone from Artifex that made the recommendation to ask elsewhere. We have been active on this thread (though for some reason I'm not getting notifications for it, which is why I haven't responded more, apologies for that)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this thread while working on a shelter-in-place project to resurrect my ImageWriter II by building Ghostscript and cups-filters for Catalina. My solution isn’t quite there yet; I can get 75% of the CUPS printer test page printed before silently crashing.

The solution for defeating sandboxing is to compile Ghostscript with dynamic linking disabled. Otherwise, even if you move the gs executable into a sandbox blessed location, the gs process will get killed as soon as it tries to link in the drivers. From my notes:

12. Download Ghostscript 9.20, the last gs with the Apple dot matrix drivers: https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/tag/gs920
13. Build Ghostscript with the drivers statically linked in (otherwise sandboxing gets you): ./configure --disable-dbus --disable-dynamic --disable-gtk --with-drivers=APPLE,PS --prefix=/usr/local/ghostscript-9.20

I have not yet tried to forward-port the iwhi drivers and such into the Ghostscript; that’s my next task, in the hope that it fixes the silent crash.

Comment: Thank you for your interest tmwong. You might be interested in having a look at the following Discussion, in which an Apple Support contributor graciously compiled a signed and notarized 64 bit version of Ghostscript: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250711255?answerId=251429513022#251429513022 It is the older 8.71 version of GS but later versions don't convey any benefit for the ImageWriter.